# How do I identify the source of water coming into my basement?

Tags: waterproofing, crawlspace

I have a ton of water coming out of the ground in my crawlspace at a specific spot after some recent heavy rain:
https://imgur.com/a/wInKUzS

After pumping for days to get the water down I noticed a spot that looked like a small bump of water and digging down a bit I saw it was quite a lot of water entering here.

I don't think it's from a pipe because it was still going after closing my main shutoff and draining the pipes. **We had a thunderstorm a few days ago, is this be runoff from that?** My house is also on the middle of a hill and next to a big storm drain so a lot of water is flowing my way.

I need help on how to diagnose the cause or which experts I need to call in to figure this out and get a fix in place.

Comment: I think that the first thing you need to do is to dig a channel to divert this water away.  We can't diagnose the cause.  Google for drainage experts.  Contact some Civil Engineering firms and ask them who to call.  They will have soil and geo-tech guys on hand.  But it probably will not be easy or cheap.

Comment: It sounds like you have a spring.

Comment: @RohitGupta I've diverted it to a low spot on the floor where I have a pump getting it out successfully. Thanks for the recommendations, I'm gonna make some calls.

Comment: @RohitGupta, answers go down there. You've short-circuited the process and no one wants to repost your comment-answer as a proper answer.

Comment: @Dav, welcome. Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: "My house is also on the middle of a hill" some landscape work might serve you well. Making hills and swales to divert water _around_ your house and toward the storm drain will help keep the exterior water from getting to the house in the first place.

Comment: test the water for chlorine content

Comment: How familiar are you with this property. If you've lived here for 50 years, then I expect that you interpret this as a new problem. If you moved in last year and just had your first big storm, then I expect that you interpret this as an old defect. If it's a new problem, then I would call whoever services that storm drain. It could also be a burst pipe upstream of your main shutoff.

Comment: @jsotola I followed your suggestion and detected no chlorine. Tested my tap water as a control and that did have chlorine so I suspect this isn't a burst pipe.

Comment: @popham I've lived here for 6 years and this is the first time I've noticed it. I have an old sump pump that has been enough for the time I've been living here but this time it was overwhelmed despite the storm being relatively normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible causes:

1. a spring under your house,
2. the level of the water table coming up because of rain, seasonal changes, or soil temperature,
3. water from the nearby storm drain finding a path to your house,
4. surface water finding a path to your basement,
5. broken pipe,
6. other.

Of these, the easiest to solve is that of surface water entering your house. The remedy is to install gutters, French drains, etc., to take that water as far away from your house as possible.

For the other possible causes, usually the only thing you can do is to pump the water out. If it's coming from the storm drain, or is a seasonal thing, then the pumping should only be necessary when the conditions merit it. But I've worked on some houses where water must be pumped out year-round.

What makes these problems so hard to solve is that water will always flow through the easiest path. It could be that you had not experienced any issues until now because water was finding a way away from your house, but the recent rainfall created a new path, and this new path goes straight under your house.

Comment: Thank you for the list of possibilities! I've called a few different places now to try to rule each one out and hopefully I can stay high and dry soon